# Add attributes to a path svg component for a map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js

I am trying to implement a strategy game that uses a svg map that I created and I would like to add some attributes like "troops" in each "path"(which would be the territory) and some other props. Is it possible to add att(props) to only a path and then use this component inside a svg tag which is the whole map. So basically I want to know how can I create a territory object with att(props) and an input or label in the map, so later I can add onClick events and other events.

For now I have the component Map and also the Territory component(I am not sure if it's the best way to deal with it.)

```
const Territory = ({ tD }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('red')
  const [troops, setTroops] = useState(21)

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" />
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d={tD} fill={color} stroke="black" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Territory;

const Map = () => {
  return (
    <svg width="1397" height="686" viewBox="0 0 1397 686" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      {territories.map(territory => (
        <Territory key={territory.id} tD={territory.tD} />
      ))}
    </svg>

  );
};
```

I want to add the troops to be visible(number) in an input or label in the map for each territory. something like this
[map with inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2v7b.png)

Is it possible to do it? what would be the best approach to build a territory component which has props like "troops"

Thank you so much whoever helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering normal `HTML <input />` as a part of `svg`, This doesn't work. If anything is not a part of `svg` and you're rendering it as a child of `svg` then you have to wrap it as a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

**Territory Component**

```js
const Territory = ({ tD }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('red')
  const [troops, setTroops] = useState(21)

  return (
    <g>
      <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="100" height="100">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </foreignObject>
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d={tD} fill={color} stroke="black" />
    </g>
  );
};
```

Note:

- Don't forget the `height` and `width` attributes. You may also need `x` & `y` too.
- Don't forget `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the container HTML element.
- You can use `svg <g />` tag to group the elements.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I just got time to see it and work on it now. It worked :) . the only thing I need to do is find the X and Y for the right positions.